# dice probability shown in histogram

Tags: java, arrays

[These are the first 14 steps](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xitPC.png) I think I was suppose to set limits.

for an assignment I was asked to write the codes for this output:

How many dice do you want? (1 to 3)

3

How many sides does each die have? (Choose an option from 2-9)

9

How many rolls? (Choose from 1000 - 2 billion)

100000000

[Histogram](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2apDT.png)

Continue? ("true" for yes and "false" for no): true

So far I have this:

```
boolean go =true; 
do {
    System.out.println("How many dice do you want? (1 to 3)");
    int dicenum = scan.nextInt();
    System.out.println("How many sides does each die have? (Choose an option from 2-9)");
    int sidenum = scan.nextInt();
    System.out.println("How many rolls? (Choose from 1000 - 2 billion)");
    int rollnum = scan.nextInt();
    int a =0;
    while (a<=rollnum){
        int [] result = new int [rollnum];
        result[a] = rand.nextInt(sidenum) + 1;

    a++;
    }
    System.out.print("Continue? (\"true\" for yes and \"false\" for no): ");
    again = scan.nextBoolean();
    if (again==false){
        go=false;
    }
    System.out.println('\n');
}while (go);
```

I am not sure how to incorporate the number of dice in the inner loop, and as the code stands I get this error:

How many dice do you want? (1 to 3)

2

How many sides does each die have? (Choose an option from 2-9)
3

How many rolls? (Choose from 1000 - 2 billion)

1000

Exception in thread "main" java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: 1000
    at project2.HistogramCLI.main(HistogramCLI.java:124)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're getting an IndexOutOfBoundsException because the last element in your result array is rollnum - 1, but with the way you have your while loop now, it goes until result[rollnum], which is what is throwing the exception.

As for incorporating the number of dice in the inner loop, I need to know what the main objective of the program is first to help you with that part.

EDIT: If you want to make a histogram like the one you linked to, then just create two for loops in your do loop. One that iterates from dicenum to (dicenum * sidenum)/2, printing out the appropriate number of stars for each total roll value in ascending order. Then for the second one, do the same thing from ((dicenum * sidenum)/2) + 1 to (dicenum * sidenum) but in ascending order.

Comment: I have to write a program that asks the user for number of dice, number of side the dice have and how many time they want to roll it. and with that information I have to display a histogram similar to the one shown in the picture, that shows probability of the rolls. I figured out where to input number of dice, but now I have to make an array to hold the result.

Comment: I did this not sure if its right tho:                                                                                                             

while (dicenum<=rollnum){
     
int [ ] result = new int [rollnum];
    
 result[dicenum] = rand.nextInt(sidenum) + 1;
    
    
dicenum++;
   
 }

Comment: It seems from the objective of the program, you don't need to generate random values, may I ask why you are doing so? Also, check my edit because that is one way to approach the drawing of the histogram.

Comment: I see what you are saying with the for loop, ill try it out, and keep you posted, thank you for the help @DaneBrick

Comment: how do I share a screen shot with you @DaneBrick

Comment: Im basically at step 6 of the instruction @DaneBrick

Comment: So my edit technically helps with the next steps since the least total sum would be diceNum (number of dice * 1) and the max total sum would be diceNum * sideNum. What else seems to be troubling?

Comment: int MAX = (dicenum*sidenum);

    int [] nums = new int [MAX];

    for (int count=0; count<=MAX ; count++){

thats how I set the max do I just repeat this step for minimum ?  @DaneBrick

Comment: According to the instructions, you actually should not make two for loops for the next step like I said in my answer. You should really just use one loop for loop starting at one and ending at rollnum like you had up there before. Then, calculate random numbers (between min and max) and increment the element in the nums array corresponding to the roll value. For example, int random = //random number; count[random]++; What I suggested earlier with the two for loops was a mistake because I thought the histogram values were predefined, not calculated by the program.